# React redux-thunk promise is pending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to react redux and just started using thunk middleware. I do get the idea of using thunk but I have hit a problem that I cant explain myself. Hoping someone would be able to help or correct me.

I am calling a function inside `render()` that dispatches a thunk action. When I `console.log` action its always pending. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. It just keeps print the following to the console.

```
Result form console.log
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Here is my thunk action creator and reducer code.

```
// actions.js
export const predictorListAction = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        function onSuccess(request) {               
          dispatch(predictorListLoadedSucessfullyAction(request.data))
          return request
        }

        try {
            const request = await axios.get(PREDICTOR_LIST_API_URL)
            return onSuccess(request)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
};


export const predictorListLoadedSucessfullyAction = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: PREDICTOR_LIST_LOADED_SUCCESSFULLY,
        payload
    };
};

// reducer.js
    const initialState = {
        results: []
    }

    export const predictorList = (state=initialState, action) => {

        switch (action.type) {
            case PREDICTOR_LIST_LOADED_SUCCESSFULLY:
                return {
                    ...action.payload
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
    };
```

And the component that I am calling everything in.

```
// component.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { predictorListAction } from '../actions/predictorListActions';

class PredictorList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.predictorListAction()
    }
    test() {
        const results = this.props.predictorListAction()
        return results
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.test())
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Predictor</h1>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        predictorList: state.predictorList
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,  { predictorListAction })(PredictorList);
```

here is the full console output that I keep getting [image]

P.S: An additional question I have is that where is the best place to call thunk actions that are doing the API calls. Currently I am doing them in `componentDidMount` but it always complains if I dont set an initial state.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but i think you should change this: `axios.get(PREDICTOR_LIST_API_URL)` to this: `axios(PREDICTOR_LIST_API_URL)`

Comment: It looks like you've an infinite loop. Calling the action within your render method means that when the reducer returns its new state, your component is re-rendered, and the action is called again (indefinitely).

Comment: @veratti: I think you are right. Didnt really considered that. Thanks

Comment: @veratti How should I fix this?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I have an onSucess function defined in the action around line 3

Comment: @tinyhook remove the `console.log(this.test())` call from render and keep it in `componentDidMount`. Like you said, you'll want an initialState since it'll render at least once before that call happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will you but i was using like below

**Import**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
```

**Add dispatch**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    predictorListAction : predictorListAction,
  }, dispatch )
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,  mapDispatchToProps)(PredictorList);
```

You can look here which I used
https://github.com/kalaikt/reactjs/blob/master/src/js/view/profile/medallion/report-problem.js